# How to render Form from a db table and POST into another db table in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have tables as below:

```
Table: data_set 
id   name 
1    set1

Table: data_set_options 
id   data_set_id   column_name   column_type   position
1        1            color       text           1

Table: product 
id    name 
1     product 

Table: product_option
id    product_id    column_name   value 
1        1            color       black
```

I have form for `data_set_options` that I can add data into database. This part also be using embedded form as `One to Many` relationship. This part is working nicely.

**Second** form `product` and `product_option` . `product_option` will be populated as `embedded` in the product form as it has `One to Many` relationship.

I have been trying to solve this way :

in `Form/ProducType.php` :

```
...
       ->add('productOption',  ProductOptionType::class, [
                'data_class' => null,
                'attribute' => $options['attribute'],
                'label' => false
            ])
...
```

AND in `Form/ProductOptionType.php`

```
...

         ->add('option', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => DataSetOption::class,
                'choice_label' => function ($option) {
                    return $option->getColumnName();
                },
                'label'     => false,
                'expanded'  => true,
                'multiple'  => true,
            ])
        ->add('value', null, [
                'row_attr' => [
                    'class' => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-9',
                ],
            ])

...
```

This solutions is not resolving my purpose as I want to set form from `data_set_options` and insert or update to `product_option`

I need your idea / help for this solution. Its open that I can modify database if you recommend better DB design.